# Example of string literal bounding array new-expression first dimension argument

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, string-literals

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> In the following cases the expression specifying the first dimension is erroneous:
>
> - the value is smaller than the number of array elements provided in the brace-enclosed initializer (including the terminating `\0` on a string literal).

Could someone provide an example for string literal being too long such that it bounds the first dimension of an array new-expression?

I don't seem to be able to come up with one :(

The only somewhat similar thing as I see is something like `auto p1 = new char[1][5]{"xyz"};` but that isn't about the first dimension.

Comment: `new char[3]{"abc"}`. Note that GCC doesn't handle this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
new const char[2]{"this is way more than one character"};
```

---

Note that gcc doesn't even compile `new const char[2]{"x"}`, but that's an orthogonal issue.

Comment: Yeah, GCC was the reason I was failing

Comment: Why https://ideone.com/gevVvP compiles fine and doesn't throw an exception, however if you uncomment the line, it crashes in VS or prints nothing in clang 4.0 https://ideone.com/3kVUqD for example?

Comment: @KillzoneKid You can't detect runtime errors at compile time?

Comment: @Barry Should throw exception or return nullptr at runtime, it doesnt do either

Comment: @KillzoneKid Looks like clang just throws `bad_alloc` instead

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone provide an example for string literal being too long such that it bounds the first dimension of an array new-expression?

Sorry but... if I understand correctly, the problem is the number of string literals, not the length of a single string literal

I mean: the problem is when you write something as

```
 auto p = new char[1][10]{"abc", "123"};
```

In the case of a 2D array of `char`.

In case of a 1D array of `char`, see the Barry's answer.

Comment: This seems to compile and run fine even though it should not https://ideone.com/egpT1H

Comment: @KillzoneKid - compile fine also with my clang++ and my g++; and run fine with my g++; but crash with my clang++.

Comment: @KillzoneKid - if I remember correctly, is UB (Undefinde Bahaviour); so can run correctly.